# Adding an item that is in a parent directory in Visual Studio C# 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

My folder structure is as follows:

Folder
      Classes
            TestClass.cs
      PlayerClass
            PlayerClass.csproj
            ............

When i go to PlayerClass => Add Existing Item and finds TestClass.cs it copies it to the PlayerClass folder. When i edit it in my project it saves it to "Folder/PlayerClass/TestClass.cs"

But i want it to save to "Folder/Classes/TestClass.cs"
And i can't use "../Classes/TestClass.cs" to define the file!

Any Ideas?

**Ok, i found out how to do it.
When you select the files there is a button called "Add".
You should press on the triangle next to it and press "Add As Link" and it works!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found out how to do it. When you select the files there is a button called "Add". You should press on the triangle next to it and press "Add As Link" and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you found the answer, hopefully the below will help anyone else.

http://cf-bill.blogspot.com/2007/10/visual-studio-sharing-one-file-between.html